# Google Sheets' filter column with data from another column using custom formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I am stuck on this for hours, I am trying to filter with custom formula

This is what I tried, why is it not working ?

```
=IFERROR(match( E1:E2, A:A , 0), 0) > 0
```

[image]

What I want to see
[image: ng]

What it shows

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use the custom filter or `FILTER` function?

Comment: Hi, I want to use the custom filter formula, because I want to filter out the rows that I don't want to see. AFAIK, the FILTER function will create a new list, I don't want a new list. I want to filter out the existing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E$1:E)&"")
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, it works well :) It should be noted also the "Filter by values" , I need all value to be "checked" also in order for the custom formula to work.